# How to apply an eslint git hook?

Tags: git, githooks, eslint

I'm not familiar with git hooks, and I've tried following the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), but I've had no luck implementing this eslint [pre-commit hook](https://gist.github.com/dahjelle/8ddedf0aebd488208a9a7c829f19b9e8). Below is a screen shot of what I've done.

[image]

When I `git add` a file, then try to commit it, all I get is:

```
[eslint-experimental 123123abc] some_message
  1 fele changed, 10 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

Why is it not linting the staged file?

Comment: The eslint path seems a relative one. Try an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your hook is in

```
<path/to/your/local/repo>/.git/hooks/
```

And make sure it is executable (chmod 755)

Comment: I can verify that it is in the correct path, but how do I check that it's executable?

Comment: @AlanH If you are on Windwos, you don't (it is executable by default). But on Linux or Mac, check the output of a `ls -alrth`: you will see the mode associated to those files.